# Sending mail with nodemailer to office@company.ro address

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemailer

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: '?',
    auth: {
        user: 'office@company.ro',
        pass: 'passHere'
    }
});
```

This is the code I'm using.

Earlier, I was sending the emails to a Gmail address, so "service" was "gmail" and it was working perfectly.

For an address like "office@company.ro" what should I pass as "service"?

Comment: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SMTP API, you should use host(hostname or IP address to connect) instead of service like this:

```
nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.example.com",  //<= add smtp server here
  port: 587, //add port
  secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
  debug: true,
  auth: {
    user: "username",
    pass: "password"
  }
});
```

For more details check [here](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/).

Comment: This is what I have:

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'mail.companyName.ro',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: 'username',
        pass: 'password'
    }
});

But it still doesn't work, any idea why? It doesn't error out, but the email doesn't arrive in the inbox/spam either

Comment: Add debug option, I have updated the answer code.

Answer (score 0):

If you add logger: true to the transporter will log all the server SMTP activity out in the console.

So to just add to the first answer, which I totally agree with:

```
    nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.example.com",  //<= add smtp server here
  port: 587, //add port
  secure: false, // upgrade later with STARTTLS
  debug: true, // show debug output
  logger: true // log information in console  **NEW**
  auth: {
    user: "username",
    pass: "password"
  }
});
```

Mailtrap wrote a little article about it that explains both debug and logger a little more: https://blog.mailtrap.io/sending-emails-with-nodemailer/